# What is a good PHP/MySQL/AJAX poll system?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Does anyone know of a good working polling system using PHP, Ajax, and MySQL to store the results?

It does not need to have any advanced features, just the basic one vote per person feature.

Comment: This is not your typical 'please give me the code to do X' site. Please show us what you have done so far, what problems you have stumbled upon and what specific questions you have that we can answer for you.

Comment: I have googled and tried many, but each one had some problem to it.
I am using  PHPKOBO AJAX POLLING SCRIPT at http://www.phpkobo.com/ajax_poll.php.
It doesn't use mysql, butso far so good. Is this a good approach using flat files?
Currently it allows users to vote multiple times, how do i make it one vote per user

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpoll/). Although it sounds like it may be a bit much for what you need, it is free, it is open source, and it does work.